# convert each line in a file into an input file

Tags: pipe, cat, gnu-parallel

I am trying to convert/use each line from a file as an input file. For example `file.txt` contains the following lines:

```
cat
dog
lion
tiger
rabbit
```

Now, using the following command:

```
cat file.txt | parallel -j 3 "cat "/path/to/tool/toolname" --dir {}.txt --log "/path/to/output/output.txt""
```

where, let's assume the converted 5 files `{}.txt` have `cat` `dog` `lion` `tiger` and `rabbit` respectively, and use the separated files as an input file individually to perform some tasks as indicated above. How can I achieve this? That is how can I convert each line inside a file into an input file first?

@Ole Tange any  thoughts on this. All other suggestions are welcome!!

Comment: `split -l1 file.txt` will split `file.txt` into new files each with one line.

Comment: Thanks @DopeGhoti I was thinking about using `split` command but how can I use the splitted file simultaneously with the parallel cat command as shown above. Can you please give me an example of using a splitted file in the command above from my initial post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cat file.txt |
  parallel --pipe -n1 --cat -j 3 "cat "/path/to/tool/toolname" --dir {} --log "/path/to/output/output.txt""
```

Example:

```
cat file.txt |
  parallel --pipe -n1 --cat wc {}

cat file.txt |
  parallel --pipe -n1 --cat 'echo File number {#} contains;cat {}'

cat file.txt |
  parallel --pipe -n1 --cat clamscan --dir {} --log sig_scan.log
```

Comment: Thanks @Ole Tange. I am getting an error stating that `cat invalid option -- 'dir'`. The option `--dir` belongs to the tool that I am using and isn't part of `cat`

Comment: @user3441801 I am copying your command. If your command is wrong, so will mine be. In other words: You need to be more explicit on what you want to run.

Comment: I am using this tool called `clamscan` (https://www.clamav.net/) which uses a user fed signature/string in a special format and scans a file to see whether the signature/string is found in the scanned file and if it does it outputs the file as infected. The basic command of `clamscan` that scans all the files in a current directory is: `clamscan --dir signature.ndb --log sig_scan.log`. Two important things to note, firstly, it only accepts the .ndb file format, secondly, I would like to scan individual signature as I mentioned in my original post.